# Combine 2 .mp4 videos

Tags: android, mp4parser

How do i combine two .mp4 videos?
I saw in google that I need to use mp4parser but the thing is, i don't know how to use it.
I downloaded and added the mp4parser library to my project in eclipse.

Can anyone give me a tutorial or any link for a beginner like me. Thank you o

Answer (score 0):

Clone this repo https://sandeep-agrawal@bitbucket.org/sandeep-agrawal/video-merger.git

It is triming videos in clips and merging them.